# Not getting text by getText() or getAttribute("innerHTML")

Tags: javascript, html, input, combobox

`getAttribute`, everything but not getting the text along perticula combobox.

I want to get the text along with each combobox.

```
<small>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="on" name="irOperations[0]"/>
  Account Activity
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="on" name="irOperations[1]"/>
  Current Day Balances
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="on" name="irOperations[2]"/>
  Current Day Transactions
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="on" name="irOperations[3]"/>
  Prior Day Balances
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="on" name="irOperations[4]"/>
  Prior Day Transactions
<br/>
<li class="xc">
</small>
```

Comment: So this is a few checkboxes with a list item at the end. How does this relate to your combobox?

Comment: Please show us the precisely js code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

1. Wrap your text with `<label></label>`
2. Connect your text with your checkbox with an `ID`
3. Then you can get the `innerHTML` from that label

Example:

**HTML**

```
<input id="account-activity" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="on" name="irOperations[0]">
<label for="account-activity">Account Activity</label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.querySelector('[for="account-activity"]').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array with "name" as index and next content of it as value

```
var comboboxes = document.getElements('input[type="checkbox"][name]');
var output = [];
comboboxes.forEach(function(combobox) {
    output[combobox.getAttribute('name')] = combobox.nextSibling.textContent.trim();
});
console.log(output);
```

or

```
document.getElement('input[type="checkbox"][name="irOperations[1]"]').nextSibling.textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

**Well you can't get innerHTML or getText of elements which are "self-contained" e.g `<input />`**

One way you do it by using HTML5 data attributes and giving each element an ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="account_activity" data-detail="Account Activity" checked="checked" value="on" name="irOperations[0]"/>
Account Activity
<br/>
```

This way you can use following JS to get the value:

```
var combo_element = document.getElementById("account_activity");
alert(combo_element.getAttribute("data-detail"));
```